# Copy full system and data partitions of Oneplus 3T to computer

Tags: oneplus-3

I've accidentally deleted some photos on Oneplus 3T and would like to get the full disk image so to be able to perform recovery using `magicrescue`:

```
magicrescue -r jpeg-exif -d output-dir disk-image.img
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442630/disk-image-dd-from-android-to-my-computer seems to answer the question but devices (/dev/***) naming on Oneplus 3T seems to differ and not standard and I'm not able to perform the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devices of system and data partitions on Oneplus 3T are the following:

```
/dev/block/dm-0
/dev/block/dm-1
```

To copy them to computer run (smartphone must be rooted):

```
adb pull /dev/block/dm-0 dm-0.img
adb pull /dev/block/dm-0 dm-1.img
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Oxygenos mounts the data partition with the discard mount argument

A trim command is sent to the storage controller as soon as you delete a file